# Issues with TRANWRD in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a list of substrings which I want to remove from a column of strings (`names`). I define the list thusly:

```
STR1 = ' - cake';
STR2 = ' - pie';
STR3 = ' - eclair';

ARRAY STR_TO_REM{*} STR1 - STR3;
```

I use the following code to remove the substrings:

```
N=1;
DO WHILE (N <= DIM(STR_TO_REM));
    STR_TO_REMOVE = TRIM(STR_TO_REM(N));
    name = TRANWRD(name,STR_TO_REMOVE,'');
    N = N+1;
END;
```

For some reason, this does not work. For example, "Joe - cake" does not get converted to "Joe". As a test, I tried directly the code

```
test = tranwrd('Joe - cake',' - cake','');
```

and obtained the expected output, indicating that at least the basic idea is sound (I know that regular expressions are a superior approach, but am more interested in understanding why the code behaves unexpectedly at this point).

However, a test for equality between `STR_TO_REMOVE` and ' - cake' fails, despite a print out of the variable looking identical. I feel that I am missing something fundamental here, and would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I wouldn't say regexes are a superior approach here; if you're doing a simple translation and only want a set of words replaced, this may well be faster, if your list isn't too terribly long.  I might do it a bit differently (particularly depending on how the list of replacements can be defined), but the `tranwrd` approach is sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your trim doesn't help where you put it.  Assuming `Str_To_Remove` is longer than any particular value, which it must be as your values are not identical in length, it must be space-padded when at rest.  As such, your trim removes spaces that are then replaced with spaces, because all SAS string variables are automatically padded with spaces to their full length.  There is no `varchar` or similar concept in SAS: a string of 10 characters contains 10 characters, no more, no less.

In this case, you must use `trim` in your `tranwrd` function call itself.  This is a common issue with `tranwrd`, to the point it's explicitly called out in the second example in the documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0pgemqcslm9uen1tvr5gcrusgrw.htm).  I don't know why they don't add an argument to ask for automatic trimming as some other functions do.

Comment: As an expression of gratitude, I shall change the example to "Joe - cake" instead of "Johnny - cake". Please let me know if another pastry/food item is more to your liking.

Comment: Would this mean, if I want to use tranwrd in this way to remove common words from a string (such as 'is', 'and' 'of' etc), I would need to trim and explicitly add trailing and leading blanks to the target in the call? Otherwise, if I trim I removed 'is' from everywhere in the string and, if I don't trim it won't find ' is ' because it will pad blanks and look for more spaces around the ' is '?

Comment: @MWallace This seems like a good question by itself, with example code.